# Normalized index between two arrays gives different result when calculate manually

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two-d arrays with the **same shape**:

```
b8
>>>array([[42,42,42,...,43,37,47],  
[41,41,40,...,44,33,34],...],dtype=uint8)

b11
>>>array([[77,77,77,...,41,41,42],
[77,77,77,...,41,41,42],...] dtype=uint8)
```

I want to use the **normalized difference index**, to  create new array.
The normalized index should be caluclated based on this formula:

> (b8-b11)/(b8+b11)

and it should produce new array with values between -1 to 1.
However, I have realized that I get unexcpected values when I try to calcualte it this way:

```
(b8-b11)/(b8+b11)
>>>
array([[1.85714286, 1.85714286, 1.85714286, ..., 0.02380952, 3.23076923,
        0.05617978],
       [1.86440678, 1.86440678, 1.87179487, ..., 0.03529412, 3.35135135,
        3.26315789],...
```

The 1.857 and the other numbers seems to be wrong, when I calculate manually the bottom left pixels I get different result:

```
(42-77)/(42+77)
>>>-0.29411764705882354
```

I believe that there is very basic concept that I'm missing here with the matrices, I would like to understand my mistake and to be able to **get the desired results.**

Comment: Please add minimal reproducible example (where you set `b8` and `b11`), because I've tried something like your code, and got values around `-0.25`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `uint8`, which is unsigned 8-bit. So your subtraction overflows:

```
np.uint8(42) - np.uint8(77)
# 221
```